# AES-CMAC in Java Card

Tags: aes, javacard, cmac

Is there a proper way of doing an *AES CMAC* encryption in Java Cards?

After researching I've hit a roadblock wherein I cannot find any example or samples of Java card that has *AES CMAC* encryption. Is there any way or at least is it possible to do an *AES CMAC* encryption on a Java Card

Answer (score 4):

There are three possibilities:

- either you take a Java Card that has an extended API that supports AES-CMAC (certain JCOP cards for example);
- you take a Java Card with API version 3.0.5 (very rare currently);
- you implement AES-CMAC from scratch using the AES Cipher and Signature objects (this is possible and not too difficult, I did this some years ago).

Comment: Is `AES_MAC_...` in `Signature` class  different from "AES_CMAC" requested in the question? It is available in JC 2.2.1 too.

Comment: no these two signature algorithms are very different

Comment: @PaulBastian It is perfectly possible to perform pre-calculation and post-calculation on AES-CBC-MAC to get AES-CMAC. It's not too difficult, did it some years ago :P

Comment: Yes this is what I meant with option number 3

Comment: @PaulBastian thanks or the input. Is there sample code or a tutorial out there in the web that I could study? I'm sorry I'm having a really hard time understanding the specs.