# Using symmetric key DES to sign and verify a message

Tags: applet, javacard

I want to know how to write an applet for sign and verify message using with DES symmetric key or AES.
I need applet code for the same in applet we should not use RSA key and key pair.
I am new to Java card please give me valuable answers I need to understand applets by basic

Comment: Please help me in this @Mjay

Comment: Look up AES-CMAC, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762644/aes-cmac-in-java-card)

Comment: Search for your answer in this site: https://javacardos.com/javacardforum/

Comment: You need to first make sure if your card support AES-CMAC. then take a look at the link Maarten shared above. If you know Java, you can write the applet using ready to use templates like this: https://javacardos.com/wiki/javacard-api-samples/aes